# How to fix Laravel token mismatch CSRF error

Tags: php, laravel

In one of my projects in Laravel I have implemented CRUD functionality and in the views for each function I have put a csrf token and a request in depending on the function i.e. PUT for updating something. I have two problems unfortunately from this. It seems to put @csrf and @method(PUT) in plain text on the html page rather than actually adding the respective functionality to the page. Also for example on the edit page when I try to edit an existing entry in the database, a token mismatch exception error appears and I'm not sure why.

Edit action in the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $blog = Blog::find($id);
    $blog->title = $request->title;
    $blog->content = $request->content;
    $blog->update();

    return redirect()->route('blog_path', ['blog' => $blog]);
}
```

Form on edit.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('update_blog_path', ['blog' => $blog->id]) }}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  @csrf

  @method('PUT')

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $blog->title}}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" rows="10" class="form-control">{{$blog->content}}</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit Blog Post</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The token mismatch error also doesn't allow me to login and register with standard Laravel authentication so I was wondering if it is a simple fix to solve this error or whether there is something more to it than that?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? `@csrf` is available in 5.6+

Comment: Im using newest release Laravel 5.8

Comment: Do you also have a CSRF field in your `<head>` section, if so, attempt removing one.

Comment: Just tried to fix it by adding a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and it comes up with a new error which is a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Now seems like my route isn't set up to allow POST.

Comment: Your route should be `Route::put` not `Route::post`.

Comment: thanks @nakov. Fixed it by extra hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and change to post (not put).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #1 - add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Solution #2 - add hidden input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: [Yevhen Kuzmenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5379944/yevhen-kuzmenko) Thank you